# React.js + Flask: After deployment, API resquest not working

Tags: python, rest, flask, deployment

I have cra app for frontend and flask for backend. I serve React with Flask and I have ejected react app.

I deployed the web app on heroku. Before deploying, I could make a request to flask server, now I can't.

My directory is like below.

```
My_webapp
├── client (front-end react)
├── static 
├── templates
├── venv
├── .env
├── .gitignore
├── email.sender.py
├── Procfile
├── requirements.txt
├── server.py (back-end flask)
```

This is my front-end side, making POST request.

```
try {
      await axios.post('/email', body, config);
      setInputData(INITIAL_INPUT_DATA);
      alert('Your email has been sent!');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
```

This is my back-end server.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from email_sender import send_email
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/email', methods=['POST'])
def email_me():
    try:
        req_data = request.get_json()
        name = req_data['name']
        subject = req_data['subject']
        content = req_data['content']
        send_email(name, subject, content)
    except:
        return 'Error on sending an email'
    return ''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8000)
```

I noticed "alert('Your email has been sent!')" works after the request, so I suspect the problem is the url that i request upon

How can I set up the proper URL for deployment?
Please advise, thank you

Comment: What's inside your `Procfile`? I'm not a heroku expert, but I suspect, it is looking for file named `app.py` rather than `server.py`, so maybe try to rename it and redeploy?

Comment: can you change await axios.post('/email', body, config); to let response= await axios.post('/email', body, config); then console.log(response) and post that aswell?

Comment: @dsadnick the problem was .env file, which I included in .gitignore. I had to commit on production branch including .env file and deploy from that branch to heroku. now it works